# Python invoking 32 bit X11 lib files instead of 64 bit while using Selenium Web driver

Tags: python, selenium, 64-bit, webdriver

I have installed python 2.7 on CentOS 5.5 x86_64 machine.

```
$ file /opt/python2.7.1/bin/python

/opt/python2.7.1/bin/python: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, AMD x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, not stripped
```

Then I tied to run a basic login script using selenium web driver & it fails with the following error.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'The browser appears to have exited before we could connect. The output was: Failed to dlopen /usr/lib/libX11.so.6\ndlerror says: /usr/lib/libX11.so.6: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32\n'
```

Why it's using 32 bit X11 library instead of using 64 bit X11 library? How can I make python use 64 bit libraries?

Comment: Sign is removed, please refer the FAQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same error on Scientific Linux 6, and tried changing the libraries as described here:
http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=2852

> Firefox 64bit + x_ignore_nofocus fails because:
>   In 64 bit mode, as we have see, the library x_ignore_nofocus
>   is looking for libX11.so.6 on the way "/usr/lib/libX11.so.6"
>   But this symlink /usr/lib/libX11.so.6 is reference to 
>   /usr/lib/libX11.so.6.2.0, which is 32bit library.

Changing the link didn't work for me, but I did not try patching selenium. Hopefully this will be fixed in the next release.

Comment: ok I solved the problem by changing the path:
sudo rm /usr/lib/libX11.so.6
sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/libX11.so.6.2.0 /usr/lib/libX11.so.6
So with firefox64bit works well

Comment: As far as I remember I also tried this, but then X11 refused to start.

Answer (score 0):

I had probably same problem and I fixed it although ugly:

My Error:

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 81, in _wait_until_connectable
    self._get_firefox_output())
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'The browser appears to have exited before we could connect. The output was: Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":1023.0".\nFailed to dlopen /usr/lib/libX11.so.6\ndlerror says: /usr/lib/libX11.so.6: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32\n'

My environment:
Fedora 14 X64
Firefox: 3.6.24 X64
Selenium 2.20.0 (webdriver)

My Ugly but easy and working fix:
I did copy file:
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/x86/x_ignore_nofocus.so
into:
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/amd64/
(Note you may want to backup the original file in case it won't work for you)